# DependencyProperty from string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

How do I convert a property name (in string) to a `DependencyProperty`?

I have a set of property names, its values in string and a `DependencyObject`. Now I want to set these property values to the `DependencyObject`. Any idea on how this can be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can get [DependencyPropertyDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.aspx) using DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromName method and then get dependency property identifier from this descriptor.

```
var descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromName(
    propertyName,
    dependencyObject.GetType(),
    dependencyObject.GetType());

// now you can set property value with
descriptor.SetValue(dependencyObject, value);

// also, you can use the dependency property itself
var property = descriptor.DependencyProperty;
dependencyObject.SetValue(property, value);
```