# How to stop storyboard but keep current values in UWP code-behind?

Tags: c#, uwp, storyboard, dependency-properties, code-behind

What is my actual problem?

I want to stop Storyboard animation but keep current value of animated properties and unfreeze those properties.

What I have tried?

I tried `storyboard.Pause()` but this will keep the animated properties frozen. (changing values has no effect) I want to be able to release all properties from storyboard.

`storyboard.Stop()` doesn't work because it either sets value of animated properties to end or start of the animation depending on the `FillBehavior`. Although it will unfreeze the properties.

I tried clearing `storyboard.Childern` but it throws exception unless storyboard is fully stopped.

I tried to make new storyboard with duration 0 with same animations, this will stop previous animations and storyboard it self will finish in no time, but here are the problems

- I should know what animations were added in last storyboard (I already solved this by storing dependency objects with property path in a List)
- I have to retrieve current value of animated properties from property path.

I am stuck at the last one because [this does not exist in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291201/dependencyproperty-from-string)

```
string propertyPath = "(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)";

// all animated properties are double
double value = (double)dependencyObject.GetValue(???);
```

`GetValue` requires `DependencyProperty` but i have a string.

---

Note: I just want a solution to my actual problem (top of this post).

Comment: What kind of effect do you actually want to have? Stop the current animation and change to another animation?

Comment: When user starts to drag element I want to stop the animation but keep `RotationY` so it will be changed by user with drag. @BarryWang-MSFT

Comment: the second storyboard i tried to make was just a hack to stop previous storyboard. second storyboard has duration of 0 and will stop soon and also stops previous storyboard so RotationY would become free to change.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT I found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using following timeline

```
new DoubleAnimation { By = 0, Duration = TimeSpan.Zero }
```

With this timeline i don't have to know value of the properties. new storyboard on same elements and same property path's with duration 0 with this timeline will stop previous storyboard and keep their values. the new storyboard will also stop in no time and unfreeze the animated properties.