# Set binding with unknown objects

Tags: c#, binding, dependency-properties, system.reflection

I'm trying to set a binding passing properties as parameters but i can't find a way on how to do it.
This works:

```
Binding bind = new Binding();
//Some code
var tb = Control as TextBlock;
tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, bind );
```

What i would like to works is similar to this:

```
public FrameworkElement Control {get;set;}
public string dp {get;set;}
public string TypeOfControl {get;set;}    

var tb = Control as typeof(TypeOfControl);
tb.SetBinding(typeof(TypeOfControl).dp, bind );
```

I've already tried to follow this:
[DependencyProperty from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291201/dependencyproperty-from-string/6291485)

```
        var descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromName(dp,typeof(TextBlock), typeof(Control));
        descriptor.SetValue(Control, bind);
```

But i get null value from descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
        Type type = Control.GetType();
        var descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromName(DependencyPropertyName, type, type);
        var dp = descriptor.DependencyProperty;
        Control.SetBinding(dp, Bind);
```

Where DependencyPropertyName in my case (testing with TextBlock) is "Text". I thought that it had to be "TextProperty".
That's why descriptor was always null.